# Consume Hyperledger composer event in Angular Based Application which uses REST API

Tags: events, hyperledger-composer

I am little new to UI freamework so please help me understand is there a way to consume an event if I have build the plain angular based app, which uses the composer rest api for UI (note: not a Node.js application)

Because as per documentation it says:
Node.js applications can subscribe to events from a business network by using the composer-client.BusinessNetworkConnection.on API call. Events are defined in the business network model file and are emitted by specified transactions in the transaction processor function file.

Redirection to blog or documentation link would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We plan to expose events through the `composer-rest-server` however that work is not yet complete. See:
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/1177

Until that work is finished you will need to subscribe to events from within your Node.js express application and then publish them (via web sockets?) to your frontend.